# Is it possible to save down HTML5 browser state including local transient data?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a HTML5 site that's only going to be used internally at my corporation. I'm trying to think of a way that we can save down the state of a user's browser window for using to debug later. Is it possible?

To clarify the question, here is the context followed by the requirements.

Context:

A HTML5 page is rendered in their browser. They have input data into a couple text fields, have interacted with Javascript which now has a local transient state, and also saved data down to LocalStorage.

Requirements:

- Save the URL the user is on, the current state of the HTML document (e.g. after any scripts such as AJAX, Bootstrap, etc have manipulated the content), the current state of Javascript variables, and a serialised version of LocalStorage. (I'll refer to all this state data as the 'snapshot').
- As long as this snapshot is saved anywhere, our systems can access it. I.e. if it's saved down to a temp folder locally we can use enterprise tools to grab it and pass it onto a developer.
- The developer will need to be able to intialise a browser state with this snapshot so that they can see what happened.

Comment: Don't you want to use server languages (as PHP, Ruby...) neither a database?  I'm asking because the users can just disable the javascript of their browsers and your whole application will not work...

Comment: Its an internal site so users will have the JavaScript enabled. Html5 will be served by tomcat but I want a way to capture intermediate state after they have affected the layout and state on the client side.